# Lost georeferencing after calculation on Geotiff in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

```
LH = gdal.Open('bandLH_output.tif')
arr_LHr = LH.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
hh_db =np.log10(ar_LHr)
```

After the above processing in python, I lost Georeferencing in image. Please suggest How I can save Array back to in Geotiff format.

Comment: I don't see how your georeference could be lost with the code shown, are you saying that when you create a new raster to save hh_db into it has no georeference? You could would need to copy your geotransform using GetGeoTransform https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Dataset.GetGeoTransform and then apply it at the end with SetGeoTransform https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Dataset.SetGeoTransform on your output raster.

Comment: hh_db, does not have georeference.

Comment: Yes, it's a numpy array not a dataset object, you need to have a osgeo.gdal.Dataset object to write the array into, it's the dataset that has georeference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if possible can you please provide any example

Answer (score 0):

An example of reading/writing and copying spatial location:

```
# this is part of a utility program that prevents
# 3 band rasters from having values of 0 or 255
# so that those values can be used as NoData

gDriver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff') # create a driver first

SrcFile = os.path.join(FromDir,sRow[0]+'.tif') # Full path to the source raster
DstFile = os.path.join(ToDir,sRow[1])          # Full path do the output raster
SrcData = gdal.Open(SrcFile,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)  # open the input raster
xsize   = SrcData.RasterXSize                  # get the column count
ysize   = SrcData.RasterYSize                  # get the row count

# now create the output raster dataset from the driver
DstData = gDriver.Create(DstFile,xsize,ysize,3,gdal.GDT_Byte,['compress=LZW'])

DstData.SetProjection(SrcData.GetProjection())     # set the output spatial reference from the source
DstData.SetGeoTransform(SrcData.GetGeoTransform()) # set the output geotransform from the source

for BandIndex in [1,2,3]:
    # loop through the bands
    SrcBandData = SrcData.GetRasterBand(BandIndex)
    DstBandData = DstData.GetRasterBand(BandIndex)
    BandArray   = SrcBandData.ReadAsArray(0,0,xsize,ysize) # read all the data from this band
    BandArray[BandArray == 0] = 1     # set all the 0's to 1
    BandArray[BandArray == 255] = 254 # set all the 255's to 254
    DstBandData.WriteArray(BandArray) # write this array to the output raster dataset
```

This shows that the array that is read is in row/column space and only when it is written to a dataset created by a driver, with its spatial reference and [geolocation](https://gdal.org/tutorials/geotransforms_tut.html) set, does the data appear in world space. Please read the [GDAL raster tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html), it has examples of python code manipulating GDAL raster dataset objects.

Comment: Thanks for posting a examples. In my case data is from SAR sensors, in which data values not lies between 0-255. Therefore, what values I need to place instead of 0-255.

Comment: That's fine, make your data type GDT_Float32 https://naturalatlas.github.io/node-gdal/classes/Constants%20(GDT).html#prop-gdal.GDT_Float32 for floating point numbers. This example is just one I had close at hand showing how to copy the geolocation onto a new dataset and write the array to it.